# Run my android activity separate to the main unity3D activity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on an an app for a client and extending the unity player activity to help me do some android specific tasks.

I do this so I can capture results from a `startActivityForResult` call, and so I can return from my activities back to Unity.

What I would like some advice on is how I can change this so it's not mixed in with my extended Unity player activity, but it is it's own activity that still captures the results and return the user back to the main Unity activity when finished.

I am hoping to not have to hide unity and instead have a new activity on the activity stack. I'm just unsure how I should go about it or if I have the thought process correct (please correct me if I am wrong)

This is my code that currently works but minimises Unity while it does my task:

```
public class MyActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity
{
    private static final String MyTag = "######";
    private static final int INSTALL_CODE = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(MyTag, "onCreate() -------------------------");
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(MyTag, "onActivityResult() -------------------------"  + requestCode + " --- " + resultCode);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == INSTALL_CODE)
        {
            // installed!
            if (resultCode == -1)
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Canvas_CloudDeploy", "AndroidAPKInstallCallback", "true");
            else
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Canvas_CloudDeploy", "AndroidAPKInstallCallback", "false");
        }
    }
 
    @Override protected void onStop()
    {
        Log.i(MyTag, "onStop() -------------------------");
        super.onStop();
    }
 
    // Quit Unity
    @Override protected void onDestroy ()
    {
        Log.i(MyTag, "onDestroy() -------------------------");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
 
    // Pause Unity
    @Override protected void onPause()
    {
        Log.i(MyTag, "onPause() -------------------------");
        super.onPause();
    }
 
    // Resume Unity
    @Override protected void onResume()
    {
        Log.i(MyTag, "onResume() -------------------------");
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Unity calling code:

```
using AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
using AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
using AndroidJavaObject unityContext = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

string packageName = unityContext.Call<string>("getPackageName");
string authority = packageName + ".provider";

AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.content.Intent");
string ACTION_VIEW = intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_VIEW);

int FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION = intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION");
int FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION = intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION");
string EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT = intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT");
int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK = intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK");

using AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", apkPath);
using AndroidJavaClass fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("androidx.core.content.FileProvider");

object[] providerParams = new object[3];
providerParams[0] = unityContext;
providerParams[1] = authority;
providerParams[2] = fileObj;

using AndroidJavaObject uri = fileProvider.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getUriForFile", providerParams);

intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
currentActivity.Call("startActivityForResult", intentObject, 100);
```

My android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <activity android:name="net.****.****.MyActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan.version" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
</manifest>
```

To summarise my questions are:

- When my activities run, because of how I call them in Unity, Unity is always stopped, then resumed. Can it simply be a new android activity running over the top of the Unity activity?
- If so, what's the right way to do it. I believe I need to call my activity from the extended unity class above, and pass in the unity context to it, so it knows how to get back once finished. But - I am a unsure. Lots of half examples to try and piece together.
- I need my activity to call back into the main unity activity once finished. It will need to send back the activity result and then resume the unity activity. I am doing this above, but want this in that separate activity class.
- If I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` I almost get the behaviour I like (Shows android activity on top of mine), [but you cant use that flag when requesting an activity result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and it wont work as desired.

Comment: To have a new activity without having to pause or hide Unity, you can use the Android Intent system. You can create a new activity and set it up to receive the results from the startActivityForResult call. Then, you can set up the new activity to return the user back to the main Unity activity when finished.

Comment: Do you mean call it via my unity code something like ```using AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("net.****.****.anotherActivity");
pluginClass.Call("startActivityForResult", intentObj, code);``` or similar? I would need to pass the Unity activity into that wouldn't I

Comment: I've added my answer. Please let me know if that's what you had in mind, you need clarity, or if it's correct mark it as such. I hope I helped!

Comment: I just noticed your last bullet point. D'oh! Then in that case use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT

Comment: Excellent, let me give this a try.

Comment: Updated my answer, as well. Wasn't able to invest as much time in detailing my answer but I do explain the flag's function a bit. Hope it's what you need!

Comment: Going to log off now but please let me know how it goes. I thought of an alternative way using a DialogFragment to launch your package installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the above information, try using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` which starts an activity as the new root of an existing task, allowing the user to navigate back to the previous task when it finishes. Unlike `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, it doesn't clear the existing task.

Be sure to note that this flag should only be used when the activity is the primary entry point of a task (which it is in your case) and doesn't have any entry point ancestors in the task's stack.

```java
using AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
using AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
using AndroidJavaObject unityContext = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

string packageName = unityContext.Call<string>("getPackageName");
string authority = packageName + ".provider";

AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.content.Intent");
string ACTION_VIEW = intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_VIEW);

int FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION = intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION");
int FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION = intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION");
int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT = intentClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT");

using AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", apkPath);
using AndroidJavaClass fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("androidx.core.content.FileProvider");

object[] providerParams = new object[3];
providerParams[0] = unityContext;
providerParams[1] = authority;
providerParams[2] = fileObj;

using AndroidJavaObject uri = fileProvider.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getUriForFile", providerParams);

intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT );
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
currentActivity.Call("startActivityForResult", intentObject, INSTALL_CODE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I missed a crucial detail in my code argh! sorry about that. I am extending the UnityPlayerActivity currently and I can get the results that's not a problem. Please see my java class signature.

My issue is the flow of this is really clunky. I don't like using the main unity task (as you noted above) as it switches between my activity and the main unity one, making it a jaded user experience.

I want to implement your suggestion - launching a second activity - passing in the unity context - and when it's done, returning. This way Unity wont hide.

Comment: 'hide' - That is switch between the Unity activity and mine. 'Stacking' the activity I believe I can do?

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. And the explanation, you have helped clarify a heap of android knowledge. 
On the VR devices I am using (running an app in 2D mode!) this does work as expected, but the unity activity still `stops` for my activity to do it's thing, and I can see this in the log. Before calling install prompt it calls `OnPause`, `OnStop`. Once I get a result, it calls `OnResume`. This may be a limitation of the android systems I am using in VR. Can I run an independent activity over the unity app? (callback to unity from the separate java class, and resume the main unity context?)

Comment: Potentially, but there is always a workaround.  It's highly likely that it's due to the new activity's behavior requirements that cause Unity to pause or lose focus. If that's the case, you can easily try intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Comment: When you start a new activity with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag, the current activity will call onPause and the new activity will call onCreate, onStart and onResume. We start a new activity that doesn't have FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, so the current Unity activity calls onPause and onStop and the new activity calls onCreate, onStart and onResume. As a result, Unity ends up losing focus and becomes paused. When you use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT in tandem, the new activity will be launched in a new task, but it will not be added to the task's back stack.

Comment: Let me give it some thought and get back to you.

Comment: Big thank you for all the help. It's an important problem to solve so the user experience is much smoother. Cheers.

Comment: Its much better now but it still minimises the unity3d app. I was able to validate this by simply clicking on the unity icon and noticing the app comes up in the same place as it was. I could 'hide' it again by clicking the icon once more. Is there some other flag I can add to prevent it from minimising?

Comment: Would love to get your input on my other problem `@Daniel Cazares` , cheers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75129226/use-an-observer-to-watch-a-settings-change-in-a-unity3d-android-application-or